# Update page as other instances of the same page changes in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my question. I have a login for a user. Many users can log in with same credentials. When user/s log in, they see a set of radio buttons. Lets say `User A`, `User B` and `User C` log in at the same time. When `User A` selects some of the radio buttons, `User B` and `User C` should also see them selected in their pages. (and vice-versa) If `User B` changes a selected radio button again, `User A` and `User C` should get that updated value in their pages. Like this most recent selections should be visible in all pages. Please help me solve this.

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You can use `AJAX` to send back selected radio to server and also retrieve them from server. Try `polling` to get latest selected radios from server.

Comment: @guradio I can only get the selected value of the radio button group.

Comment: @Parixit Can you please send me a link to a possible approach with this?

Comment: So basically trying to live stream the actions done in one client and show the same actions on the other clients??

Comment: Yes sort of... Trying to show the radio button selections on all clients.

Comment: I think you should check out about webRTC. It basically is meant for these type of things...

Comment: @dvenkatsagar webRTC looks interesting, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar setup awhile back, when user switches department view, all open pages of the application prompt him about the change and switch to the active department view.

I did it as follows.

Stored desired variables in user session. In your case, since you need this available across multiple users, session won't do - store it in a database or flat file. These variables are updated on radio `onChange` event in your case.

Make the following JS  available to relevant pages. Note, I used `onFocus` since that was I needed, you may need to use `setInterval()`

```
window.onfocus = function(e) {
var_check();
};

function var_check(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'home/check_vars_ajax',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data : {[YOUR DATA]}
}).done(function(data){
    // ...
    // handle selecting releavant radio buttons here
});
}
```

To summarize:

1. Write your radio selection to DB or flat file (via AJAX)
2. Setup a heartbeat call to check current status on the server (AJAX)
3. Update radio selection accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Well another way to do it would be to go for `WebRTC` which basically allows you to screen share the users page and show the results on the other users or vice versa. It has very neat API and there are lot of samples that you can check out. Tutorials are available and their homepage itself is a good starting point

But with regard to your particular problem, I cannot give you a clear answers as the question itself is little broad(in my opinion). So check it out and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple database query. How it works is, when someone logs into a page, it grabs a variable from a database row. At a set time, the page queries the database. if the value has changed in the database, update that row by one. the other pages will query at your set interval, and update the page with AJAX. It is a nifty way to update all pages at once. Here is a tutorial in this.
[AJAX auto refresh](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii/)

You can see a modified example on my request box on this page
[AutoRoxx Radio](http://autodude666.com/network)

It is easily modified. Basics are there.